# A question about algebraic closures of fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An algebraic closure of a field $F$ is defined in the following way

> Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$. Then $$\overline{F}_E=\{\alpha\in E|\alpha\text{ is algebraic over $F$}\}$$

My book and this [wikipdia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) states that every algebraic closure of $F$ is isomorphic.

1. Let the field under consideration be $\Bbb{Q}$. How can $\overline{\Bbb{R}}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ ever be isomorphic to $\overline{\Bbb{C}}_{\Bbb{Q}}$? $\overline{\Bbb{C}}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ clearly contains more elements ($i$ for example). Come to think about it, this is a bad idea, as ain intuitively bigger and an intuitively smaller field may be isomorphic. Look at $\Bbb{Q}$ and $8\Bbb{Q}$.
2. It may be possible that when we say algebraic extension of field $F$, we fix the field extension $E$. But if the field extension is fixed, isn't $\overline{E}_{F}$ unique? Why I think it is unique is that $\overline{E}_{F}$  simply contains **all** elements in $E$ that are algebraic over $F$. How can this not be unique?

Comment: You are mixing two things. The displayed definition is «the algebraic closure of $F$ **in** $E$» while the things denoted by `\overline`'s refer to absolute algebraic closures, which are a rather different beast. On the other hand, you wrote things like $\overline{\mathbb R}_{\mathbb Q}$, which do not make any sense: your displayed definition of $\overline F_E$ is for $E$ an extension of $F$, and $\mathbb Q$ is not an extension of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez- Oh, so algebraic closures in general can be any field that is algebraically closed over $F$? Is $F$ also an algebraic closure over $F$ then?

Comment: $F$ is an algebraic closure of $F$ in itself, for example.

Comment: I would suggest that you forget about the Wikipedia article and read rather a more well thought out exposition of this in a textbook; there are several around

Comment: Any two absolute algebraic closures are isomorphic; relative absolute closures need not be isomorphic. You are confusing the two notions.

Comment: $8\mathbb Q$ is just $\mathbb Q$...